# Android SD card directory folders name list

Tags: android, directory

How can I get names of all folders (not files) in specific directory on SD card? For example all subfolders names in `/sdcard/first_level_folder/...`.

I need folder name, so I can pass complete path (string) to the method which will then compress (zip) it.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks everyone for answers... problem solved :)

Comment: can u pls tell me how u resolve your issue ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Step #1: Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the root of external storage. `/sdcard/` is incorrect on most devices.

Step #2: Use the appropriate `File` constructor to create the `File` object pointing to your desired directory inside external storage.

Step #3: Use [Java I/O](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/GetFiles.html) to find what is in that directory.

Answer (score 12):

I think what you are looking for is

```
File dir = new File("directoryPath");
FileFilter fileFilter = new FileFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.isDirectory();
    }
};
File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
```

Answer (score 3):

Well you can use something like:

```
File file[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();  


for (File f : file)
{
    if (f.isDirectory()) { ... do stuff }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

well this is a java related question.
Check [this](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/GetFiles.html) out.

To get access to the sdcard folder name :

```
File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String SD_PATH = extStore.getAbsolutePath()+"your sd folder here";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File file=new File("/mnt/sdcard/");
        File[] list = file.listFiles();
        int count = 0;
        for (File f: list){
            String name = f.getName();
            if (name.endsWith(".jpg") || name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".some media extention"))
               count++;
            System.out.println("170 " + count);
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
File file[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();  


for (File f : file) {
    if (f.isDirectory()) { 
        // ... do stuff 
    }
}
```

Step #1: Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the root of external storage. `/sdcard/` is incorrect on most devices.

Step #2: Use the appropriate `File` constructor to create the `File` object pointing to your desired directory inside external storage.

Step #3: Use [Java I/O](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/GetFiles.html) to find what is in that directory.

Comment: Your answer appeared in the "Low quality" review queue, because it only contains a block of code. Please explain what the code does, and why it works, to improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: Step #1: Use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to get the root of external storage. /sdcard/ is incorrect on most devices.

Step #2: Use the appropriate File constructor to create the File object pointing to your desired directory inside external storage.

Step #3: Use Java I/O to find what is in that directory.

Comment: ... In the answer itself. Not in the comments.