# Save images from within app to wallpaper folder in gallery

Tags: android

I have few wallpapers saved in drawable folder. I want save these images in wallpapers folder. For now my images are getting saved in camera folder. Using this code.

```
Bitmap w1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.wallpaper03);

Images.Media.insertImage(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                w1, "", "");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save image to sdcard from drawble resource on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558053/save-image-to-sdcard-from-drawble-resource-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

As I have understand your questions 
  **U need wallpapers directory in memory,**
  **U need to save your drawable images to  that directory**

Create wallpapers directory or folder , if not exist 
[Create folder in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794974/create-folder-in-android)

how to save images from drawable to phone memory [save image to device memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558053/save-image-to-sdcard-from-drawble-resource-on-android)

Comment: No i don't want create a new folder. Rather want to save it in the built in wallpaper folder of phone. Is it possible ?

Comment: yes it is possible. but you need to confirm that there is any wallpapers folder......
try to get name of folders exist in phone, using this link..... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917860/android-sd-card-directory-folders-name-list......... if there is wallpapers folder exist in list. then take path of that folder and save images to that folder... otherwise use above method

Answer (score 1):

### Saving image to sdcard from drawble resource:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

The path to SD Card can be retrieved using:

```
String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/FOLDERNAME/";
```

Then save to sdcard on button click using:

```
File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "ic_launcher.PNG");
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
```

Don't forget to add **`android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`** permission.

a complete sample project: **[SAMPLE PROJECT](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/save-image-into-sd-card-in-android/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
  void Save(){  
String folder = "/sdcard/Pictures/MyAppFolder";
       Imageview  view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cachesView);

          view.buildDrawingCache(); 

        Bitmap yourBitmap = view.getDrawingCache();  
          final File myDir = new File(folder);
                myDir.mkdirs();
                final Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 10000;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                final String fname = "StyleMe-" + n + ".png";
                File file = new File(myDir, fname);
                if (file.exists())
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    yourBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                            Uri.parse("file://"
                                    + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()))); // this will refresh the gallery app.
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
    }
```

### please see

add this method in your class and on click button put

```
Save();
```

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680743/how-to-save-image-from-drawable-resource-to-sd-card) as answered by [k0sh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1627904/k0sh)